# Wrong value in NSUInteger. Why?

Tags: ios, nsnumber, nsuinteger

This is how my MyManager numberOfBedrooms property is set:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger numberOfBedrooms;
```

This is how I assign the value to it from a textbox:

```
 myManager.numberOfBedrooms = (NSUInteger) self.bedroomTextField.text;

When i enter a 1 in text box, and do the following, I get large values like 304284 WHy?

NSLog(@"bedrooms is: %@", [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt: myManager.numberOfBedrooms] );
NSLog(@"bedrooms is: %d", myManager.numberOfBedrooms );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
 myManager.numberOfBedrooms = (NSUInteger) [self.bedroomTextField.text intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this casting (you're converting an object to an int):

```
myManager.numberOfBedrooms = (NSUInteger) self.bedroomTextField.text;
```

You should do something like:

```
myManager.numberOfBedrooms = [self.bedroomTextField.text intValue];
```

Comment: why intValue and not IntegerValue?

Comment: "intValue" is an instance method of NSString, which is the object returned in a UITextField's .text property. "IntegerValue" is not.